# Extract specific value from a PHP string

Tags: php, string, twitter, extract

I am trying to learn the max_id of a tweeter result for the dynamic pagination.

The search metadata are the following:

```
search_metadata: {
  completed_in: 0.033,
  max_id: 326811859678277600,
  max_id_str: "326811859678277634",
  next_results: "?max_id=326811400389406719&q=%23helloworld&count=10&include_entities=1",
  query: "%23helloworld",
  refresh_url: "?since_id=326811859678277634&q=%23helloworld&include_entities=1",
  count: 10,
  since_id: 0,
  since_id_str: "0"
}
```

It would be very handy to my script convert `max_id` on next results to a php value.

Is there a way therefore to extract the number `326811400389406719` (and any other number like that from the `?max_id=326811400389406719&q=%23helloworld&count=10&include_entities=1` string ?

Thanks!

Comment: [parse_str](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-str.php) might help you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$str = "?max_id=326811400389406719&q=%23helloworld&count=10&include_entities=1"    
parse_str($str, $output);
$max_id = $output['?max_id'];
//print_r($output);
```

Comment: $str = substr("?max_id=326811400389406719&q=%23helloworld&count=10&include_entities=1",1); //to drop the first "?"

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions?

```
$string = '?max_id=326811400389406719&q=%23helloworld&count=10&include_entities=1';

preg_match('/max_id=(\d+)/', $string, $matches);
$max_id = $matches[1];
```